# php set s3 content-disposition as attachment

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I want to set the content-disposition as attachment in a s3 bucket while

uploading file to S3 bucket ,below is my code im using.

```
$s3 = new S3(AWS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY);

 if ($s3->putObjectFile("$uploadDir/$file", AWS_BUCKET, "$targetDir/$file", S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)) {
$syncSize = $s3->getObjectInfo(AWS_BUCKET, "$targetDir/$file");

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add contentDisposition in putobject in php as **'ContentDisposition' => 'attachment',**

```
$result = $client->putObject(array(
  'Bucket'     => $bucket,
  'Key'        => $fileName,
  'SourceFile' => $fileTempName,
  'ContentDisposition' => 'attachment',
  'Metadata'   => array(
    'Foo' => 'abc',
    'Baz' => '123'
  )
 ));
```